# What is "symbol" in JetBrains IDE's

Tags: webstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using WebStorm and it has a concept of a "Symbol". For example, I can [view Symbol usages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/2017.1/viewing-usages-of-a-symbol.html?search=symbol). It locates all methods of classes.

So what is Symbol? A class method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd say that '**Symbol**' there mostly means '**Identifier**' - it can be a class/function/variable, CSS selector, HTML tag, etc.

Comment: thanks, is there a list of all the things it looks for?